# Kendo Grid multi column group based on object array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I am relatively new to `MVC` (and `Kendo`) but I have managed to setup a grid which contains multi column headers using the `columns.Group` functionality.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Result>()
            .Name("myGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.ResultDateTime).Title("Date Time");

                foreach (Lot Lot in (Lot[])ViewBag.Lots)                
                {
                    columns.Group(group => group
                        .Title(Lot.LotNumber)
                        .Columns(info =>
                        {
                            info.Bound(Lot.Result.Count.ToString());
                            info.Bound(Lot.Result.Mean.ToString());
                            info.Bound(Lot.Result.SD.ToString());
                        }));
                }
                columns.Bound(c => c.StandardComment.Description).Title("Comment");
                columns.Bound(c => c.ReviewComment.Description).Title("Review Comment");
                columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); });
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable
                .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
                .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true))
            .Pageable()
            .Navigatable()
            .Sortable()
            .Groupable()
            .Scrollable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Batch(true)
                .PageSize(20)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Read("ResultsAsync_Read", "ResultEntry")
                .Destroy("ResultsAsync_Destroy", "ResultEntry")
             )
        )
```

As you can see I am trying to build the columns dynamically based on an array which has been setup and passed using `ViewBag`.

Controller async function which sets up `ViewBag.Lots` extracting the array from the top level `IEnumerable<Result>` object:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ResultsAsync_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {                
            IEnumerable<Result> controlSets = await _manager.ReadAsync(test);            
            ViewBag.Lots = controlSets.Select(x => x.LotResults);
            return Json(controlSets.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

When I run this, I get the following error when trying to access the `ViewBag.Lots` attribute in the `foreach`.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Does someone know why I am getting this error and also if there is a more efficient way to achieve my goal?

**EDIT:**
Instead of using the ViewBag to hold the list of `Lot` objects, I am using it to hold the maximum number of lots available in the entire `List<Result>`s. 
I have taken @ken2k's advice onboard and done this within the `Index()` function of the Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            QCTest test = new Models.Acusera.QCTest();
            test.TestID = 3;
            IEnumerable<Result> controlSets = await _manager.ReadAsync(test);
            ViewBag.MaxLots = controlSets.Max(x => x.LotResults.Count);
            return View("~/Views/Acusera/DataEntry/ResultEntry.cshtml");
        }
```

Then I loop over the maximum number of lots available and create the columns required:

```
.Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.ResultDateTime).Title("Date Time");

                    for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.MaxLots; ++i)
                    {
                        columns.Group(group => group
                            .Title("Test")
                            .Columns(info =>
                            {
                                info.Bound(x => x.LotResults[i].Result.Count);
                                info.Bound(x => x.LotResults[i].Result.Mean);
                                info.Bound(x => x.LotResults[i].Result.SD);
                            }));
                    }
                    columns.Bound(c => c.StandardComment.Description).Title("Comment");
                    columns.Bound(c => c.ReviewComment.Description).Title("Review Comment");
                    columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); });
                })
```

This results in a grid displaying like so:

[image]

So I have managed to create the number of multi-header columns required to display the data. However, I am now getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Result' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

Your `ResultsAsync_Read` method is an async method that will be called by the Kendo framework from a javascript AJAX call, i.e. **after** your page has been loaded and rendered.

This means that **when your page is rendered**, `ViewBag.Lots` is actually null, which throw the exception.

What you need is to initialize this value **when you load the page, not inside your `ResultsAsync_Read` method**. Basically:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    // Gets the values BEFORE rendering the view
    IEnumerable<Result> controlSets = await _manager.ReadAsync(test);

    // The ViewBag property will be available from the Razor view            
    ViewBag.Lots = controlSets.Select(x => x.LotResults);

    // Returns the view that display the grid
    return this.View();
}
```

It's important to remember how the MVC stuff actually works. Basically the steps are:

- the server receives a request on the .../Index route
- the server executes the Index() action
- as the action returns this.View() (which would be equivalent to this.View("Index")), it renders the Index.cshtml razor view (that means the ViewBag must be not null here)
- if later you do AJAX calls such as `ResultsAsync_Read`, changing the ViewBag **won't have any effect as the page is already rendered**. The only thing you could do to modify your page, is to return some JSON, and change the DOM based on the JSON result **from inside your AJAX callback** (i.e. using jQuery/javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the info @ken2k. I appreciate the response. This action will definitely be required later (in order to rebind the grid based on a different user selection). Therefore, is there a way I can directly use the `Lot` array object through the razor grid view setup?

Comment: @Sandman Not sure to understand, will you need to dynamically change your columns once the page is loaded (I mean using AJAX) ?

Comment: yes, when the user makes a different `test` selection, new values need to be retrieved from the database.  The `Lot[]` length can vary anywhere from 1 to 6 therefore meaning I will need to create 1 to 6 columns based on the `test` selected.

Comment: @Sandman Then it's gonna be easier to reload the whole view (so 1/ you populate your ViewBag within the Index action 2/ the page is rendered _again_ with new columns). If you need to change your columns dynamically (i.e. through AJAX without reloading the whole page), it's gonna be a bit hard to implement.

Comment: Ok, so I have updated my question in line with some edits I have made to the code. I now use the `ViewBag` to hold the maximum number of `Lot` objects available in the entire `List<Result>`s but have run into another snag. Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance