# Kendo Grid bind to datatable converted from List<T> which contains array of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable, kendo-grid

I have converted a `List` of objects (`List<Result`>) based on stored procedure results. The object `Result` contains a number of base type attributes, an `array` of objects (type `Lot`) which can vary in size and a couple of other objects (`Comment`, `ReviewComment`):

```
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResultDateTime { get; set; }
    public string EnteredByInitials { get; set; }
    public int ControlSetLotCount { get; set; }
    public Lot[] LotResults { get; set; }
    public Comment StandardComment { get; set; }
    public ReviewComment ReviewComment { get; set; }
```

I have then converted this list into a `DataTable` in order to bind successfully to a `Kendo Grid` control.

The function I used to accomplish a successful conversion is below:

```
private static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Props[i].PropertyType == typeof(int) || Props[i].PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        //inserting property values to datatable rows
                        values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                    }
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }

            PropertyInfo[] propList = items.GetType().GetProperties(); //This will get all property with property name
            foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in propList)
            {
                if (pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int) || pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    //Just get the value and insert to your table
                    object propValue = pInfo.GetValue(items, null); //Notice this is not fit for array type
                }
                else
                {
                    //This is embeded object
                    string thisPropName = pInfo.Name; //Get the property name. Here should be UserType
                    object propValue = pInfo.GetValue(items, null); //Then you can use this object to get its inside property name and value with same method above.
                }
            }            
            return dataTable;
        }
```

Binding this `DataTable` results in the following:

[image]

As you can see, this is not what I want the end result to be.  I want to display 'n' number of multi-header columns based on the size of the `Lot` array which contain their own individual attributes as well as the individual attributes of the `Comment` objects. Is there a way I can manipulate the `DataTable` in the `razor` view to achieve this? Failing that, is there a way to setup the `DataTable` in such a way that these object attributes are accessible?

I have currently setup the `Kendo Grid` control as follows (and have been experimenting with looping over the location of the `LotResults` column with no success):

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
                .Name("resultGrid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    var lotResults = Model.Columns[4];
                    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        if (column.ColumnName == lotResults.ColumnName)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                            columns.Bound(column.ColumnName);

                    }
                    columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Destroy());                    
                })
                .Editable(editable => editable
                    .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
                    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true))
                .Pageable()
                .Navigatable()
                .Sortable()
                .Groupable()
                .Scrollable()
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Batch(true)
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .ServerOperation(false)
                    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                    .Read("ResultsAsync_Read", "ResultEntry")
                    .Destroy("ResultsAsync_Destroy", "ResultEntry")
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        var id = Model.Columns[0].ColumnName;
                        model.Id(id);
                        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            var field = model.Field(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
                            if (column.ColumnName == id)
                            {
                                field.Editable(false);
                            }

                        }
                    })
                 )
        )
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use the `DataTable` type, nor why you used `dynamic`. Why not directly use `Result` or some ResultModel/ResultDto type?

Comment: My initial approach was using `List<Result>` directly onto the grid but ran into issues when trying to extract each `Lot` object and creating a column. Please take a look at my previous question describing that approach.  Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Link - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631743/kendo-grid-multi-column-group-based-on-object-array)

Comment: For kendo grids with dynamic columns, I would prefer javascript over razor. It is easier to implement the column and datasource configurations on the go in js.